# Integral of derivative of $f(t,t)$ wrt one argument only

Tags: integration

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Consider the following expression two expressions:
\begin{align}
\int_a^b \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} f(t,\tau) \right]_{\vert\tau=t}  dt ,
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\int_a^b \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} f(\tau,t) \right]_{\vert\tau=t}  dt ,
\end{align}

where the subscript $\tau = t$ indicates evaluation at $\tau = t$.

I'm trying to understand if there is some nice relationship between these two integrals. I feel like it has something to do with integration-by-parts, but I don't see how to apply integration-by-parts since there is only one function not two.

Something in the spirit of summation-by-parts works in the discrete case as I show below.

#### Discrete Case:

Corrected:

\begin{align}
& -f(T,T) + \sum_{t=1}^{T-1} \left[ f(t,t+1) - f(t,t) \right]
\\ &= -f(1,1) - \sum_{t=1}^{T-1} \left[ f(t+1,t+1) - f(t,t+1) \right]
\end{align}

In the discrete case, this is what I want. I'd like to find the analog in the continuous case. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of notation, I'll denote
$$
f_1(x, y)
= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y), 
\qquad
f_2(x, y)
= \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y),
$$
so that the integrals that you're interested in are $\int_a^b f_2(t, t)\, \mathrm{d}t$ and $\int_a^b f_1(t, t)\, \mathrm{d}t$ respectively.

But the multivariate chain rule yields that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} f(t,t)
= f_1(t, t) + f_2(t, t),
$$
so that
\begin{align*}
f(b, b)
- f(a, a)
&= \int_a^b \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} f(t,t) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_a^b f_2(t, t)\, \mathrm{d}t + \int_a^b f_1(t, t)\, \mathrm{d}t,
\end{align*}
which is analogous to your discrete case.

Comment: Thank you. Now I feel dumb I didn't think of that.